# Command not found when run with sudo bash

Tags: shell, sudo, path

I ssh into my machine and then, in order to run some commands, I need to `sudo bash` first.

In an interactive terminal session, if I do this:

```
[vagrant@33 ~]$ sudo bash
[root@33 vagrant]# which bundle
/opt/upnxt/rbenv-0.4.0-7/shims/bundle
```

things work. But if I need to do this in one line:

```
[vagrant@33 ~]$ sudo bash -c "whoami; which bundle"
root
which: no bundle in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

things stop working. Why is this happening and what else do I need to do to the second scenario in order to be able to run it like the first one?

Comment: "which: no bundle in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)" <--- hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sudo bash` you run new instance of bash with `user root environment`. But if you call `sudo bash -c "whoami; which bundle"` the environment is remain as for your user. If you havn't intention to do so you can modify last call by `sudo` options `-i`

> **-i**, **--login**
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as *.profile* or *.login* will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's **-c** option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  **sudo** attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The command is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  The *Command Environment* section in the **sudoers**(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.